# How to fill shopping cart on page B with data from page A

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a list of products on page A and want to add them to a shopping cart on an  external page B (by clicking a button on page A). I already have the correct Ids from page B and their single product page url. I'm looking for the correct (and secure) approach on this one.

My current approach would be using a browser extension which passively listens to the specific button click on page A and then takes action (e.g. by automatically opening a new tab and submit every product page individually). Extending this idea a bit further I could check the form submit url of page B and make use of it automatically.

However using an extension limits this feature to desktop only.
I already thought about using a bookmarklet but using that approach a user always has to actively activate the bookmarklet (from what I know) instead of it listening passively ...

Am I on the right track here or is there another different way I could go?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your item id to a variable array each time you select one and then pass the array variable to the page B either by using arguments or using a POST method.

Comment: Page B is an external page I can't read/modify on that page (except when using an extension). I modified my original question.

Comment: If it's an external page, you cannot interact with it (except maybe if the user has an extention installed in its browser and you use that as a middlemen). It's a good thing, because allowing that would create all sorts of security issues.